# How can I receive the file contents in my Vaadin service?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin12

I want to add an upload button to my web application. In the HTML template, I added:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/vaadin-upload/src/vaadin-upload.html">

<h2 id="header-Upload">Upload</h2>
<vaadin-upload nodrop/>
```

I now want to receive the stream in my backend Vaadin process. This stream can be then inserted in the database.

The documentation on https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload/html-examples/upload-basic-demos doesn't provide this information.

I believe I should somehow link a `StreamReceiver` to the `<vaadin-upload>` in question, but I am not sure how to do that.

I am using Vaadin Flow (version 12).

**Additional information**

I tried the following:

In HTML:

```
<vaadin-upload id="upload" nodrop/>
```

In Java:

```
public class MyView extends PolymerTemplate<Model> {
    private final MemoryBuffer buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
    @Id("upload")
    private final Upload       upload = new Upload(buffer);

    public MyView() {
        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
            System.out.println(event.getFileName());
            System.out.println(buffer.getInputStream());
        });
    }
}
```

When I upload a file, I get the following exception:

```
[qtp162821120-20] ERROR com.vaadin.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler - 
com.vaadin.flow.server.UploadException: Upload failed
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.StreamReceiverHandler.streamToReceiver(StreamReceiverHandler.java:429)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Upload cannot be performed without a receiver set
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.upload.Upload$DefaultStreamVariable.getOutputStream(Upload.java:581)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.StreamReceiverHandler.streamToReceiver(StreamReceiverHandler.java:358)
```

Comment: Are you creating an Upload instance in java, or is this about doing it only in html?

Comment: If you are using it in Java, you can try giving it an id, e.g. `<vaadin-upload id="upload" nodrop/>` and in your corresponding Java file bind it with `@Id("upload) private Upload upload` and do the rest from there.

Comment: @Cashbee I was trying to define the button in HTML and do all callback/stream handling in Java. See my update in the question.

Comment: @Tazavoo I tried that, but I am getting an exception I cannot explain. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**massive Edit**: The actual solution to your problem was that you instantiated the `Upload` in your java class, when you should let Vaadin do this (because of the polymer template) and refer to this upload component using an identifier both in the html template (`<vaadin-upload id="upload" nodrop/>`) as well as in the java code (`@Id("upload") private Upload upload;`). You can now set the receiver of the upload in the java class using `upload.setReceiver(buffer);`.

```
public class MyView implements PolymerTemplate<Model> {

    @Id("upload") // com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate
    private Upload upload; // NO INSTANTIATION!
    private private final MemoryBuffer buffer = new MemoryBuffer();

    public MyView (){
        upload.setReceiver(buffer);
        upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
            System.out.println(event.getFileName());
            System.out.println(buffer.getInputStream());
        });
    }
}
```

My initial answer was using an unnecessary alternative approach that was not related to your problem (I thought so at first), but helped finding the real solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution depends a bit about your context, mainly how does your backend accept the data? Does it accept inputstream where it can read the data, does it provide you an outputstream where to write it or is there a simple byte[] where to buffer the content.

If you are using Binder in your form, you could use ByteArrayUploadField from Viritin add-on, which directly binds to byte[] type that you probably have in your domain object.

I recently wrote [an article that explains the functionality of Vaadin Upload](https://vaadin.com/blog/uploads-and-downloads-inputs-and-outputs) component. Check that for more details.